# How to get the difference between two sparse matrices?

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I have two sparse matrix, and want to get the difference between the two sparse matrix.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix,find

row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
sparse_matrix = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))
print(sparse_matrix.toarray())

row2= np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
col2= np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2])
data2= np.array([1, 4, 5, 2, 6])
sparse_matrix2 =csr_matrix((data2,(row2, col2)),shape=(2,3))
print(sparse_matrix2.toarray())
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 0 2]
 [0 0 3]
 [4 5 6]]

[[1 0 2]
 [4 5 6]]
```

**Expected:**

I want to get a sparse matrix, and it's dense matrix is shown as follow.

```
[[0 0 3]]
```